# Return Yes if only one record is found

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has this structure:

```
table
id      | site_id
-------------------
240     | 1
240     | 2
240     | 3
320     | 1
320     | 2
421     | 1
520     | 2
-------------------
```

300k records

Now i am trying to write a query to return a yes or a no for each record (id).

For example if the records with id 240 **only** have a site_id 1 then return 'Yes', if it has 2, 3 and so on return 'No'

I am not sure how to approach it but here is a result sample:

```
result_table
.-----------------------.
| id        | result    |
|-----------------------|
| 240       |   No      |  -- has a site_id 1, 2 and 3
| 320       |   No      |  -- has a site_id 1 and 2
| 421       |   Yes     |  -- has a site_id 1 only
| 520       |   No      |  -- has a site_id  2
'-----------------------'
```

Here is the query i have so far, but it seems to be incorrect

```
SELECT CASE WHEN count(id) > 1 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END as Result 
FROM table sm 
WHERE sm.site_id IN (1) 
AND sm.site_id NOT IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) 
AND id = 240
```

**UPDATE**

SO Here is my full query, i added the answer from @gordon

```
SELECT 
    m.merchant_name,
    m.merchant_id,
    ut.realname,
    a.affiliate_name,
    (select (case when count(site_id) = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as result
    from site_merchant sm
    WHERE sm.merchant_id = m.merchant_id
    group by merchant_id) as isTjoos,   -- y or no
    (select (case when count(site_id) = 2 then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as result
    from site_merchant sm
    WHERE sm.merchant_id = m.merchant_id
    group by merchant_id) as isUCOnly
--  isdlkonly   -- y or no
FROM merchant m
LEFT JOIN merchant_editor_assignment mea ON mea.merchant_id = m.merchant_id
LEFT JOIN user_table ut ON ut.user_id = mea.user_id
LEFT JOIN affiliate a ON a.affiliate_id = m.affiliate_id_default
```

Comment: @lbu . . . There are multiple ways to interpret your question.  Can you elaborate?  In particular, are you looking for ids that have exactly 1 row with site_id = 1?  Are you looking for ids that have only rows with site_id = 1?  Or, are you looking for ids all of whose rows have the same site_id?

Comment: This is a subquery i will be looking for other records that will have site_id 2 and only 2, and 3 and only 3;

Comment: @Ibu: Take a look at my answer that `SUM`s the site_id.

Answer (score 3):

I interpreted this question as you want ids that have only one value for site_id.  I took the example in the question to be an example, with site_id = 1.  To do this:

You want to use `count(distinct)`:

```
select id, (case when count(distinct site_id) = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as result
from site_merchant sm
group by id
```

A slightly more efficient version is to use `min()` and `max()`, assuming that the site_id is never NULL:

```
select id, (case when min(site_id) = max(site_id) then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as result
from site_merchant sm
group by id
```

This is because min and max generally require a bit less processing than `count(distinct)`.

If you want to check that the site_id is "1" and never anything else, then add the condition `and min(site_id) = 1` to the `when` clause.

If you want to check that the site_id is 1 and there is exactly one row, then you can do:

```
select id, (case when count(site_id) = 1 and min(site_id) = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as result
from site_merchant sm
group by id
```

And, if you want to check that there is exactly one row:

```
select id, (case when count(site_id) = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as result
from site_merchant sm
group by id
```

Comment: Amazing, this returns the result i want, i will have to study it to understand what is happening

Comment: maybe it's better to use `case when min(site_id)=max(site_id) and min(site_id)=1`? anyway it's a great idea to use min and max, +1

Comment: @Ibu: Correct me if I am wrong. You are looking to show Yes only if there exists an only record for site_id = 1. I don't think the above handles it (atleast from the example you gave). i.e. What if there is a single record for id=421 with site_id = 2? Should it show "Yes"?

Comment: if there is a single record for id=421 with site_id = 2 it should show "No"

Comment: @Ibu: The first 2 queries don't handle that. However, the 3rd query added by Gordon handles it.

Comment: @Gordon Looks like these work well only for my first case where site_id is 1, see my updated query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  it,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN site_id THEN 1 END)=1
            AND COUNT(CASE WHEN site_id!=1 THEN 1 END)=0 THEN 'Yes'
       ELSE 'No'
  END
FROM sm
GROUP BY it
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b155/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, CASE WHEN EXTRA > 1 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS Result
FROM
(SELECT ID, Sum(site_id) AS Extra
 from myTable
 GROUP BY ID
) AS Test
```

EDIT: I suppose this should work in MySQL. I haven't worked on it though.
The idea is to `SUM` up the site_id. For records with **only** site_id = 1, the sum will be 1.

Comment: So this works fine for my query when i am looking for site_id=1, but when do the same when i am looking for those with site_id = 2, or 3 the some is no longer relevant

Comment: @Ibu: The query returns Yes for ID having site_id = 1 (only 1 record), returns No otherwise. It certainly fetches data matching the sample output you are looking for.

Comment: See my updated query, looks like it works well for the site_id 1 only

Comment: @Ibu: I think your query is incorrect. What if you have an ID= 500 with site_id = 2 (and that is the only record for ID=500)?

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems overcomplicated. Just to start, why the `IN(1)` and `NOT IN(2,3...9)`? And why limit to a single ID (`AND id = 240`) when your "result sample" clearly doesn't want that? It does not make any sense. How about this?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN count(merchant_id) > 1 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END as isTjoos 
FROM site_merchant
GROUP BY site_id;
```

Comment: i don't understand what this does really, but i am trying it

Comment: This doesn't take care of scenario where there is 1 record with site_id = 2. I suppose OP is looking at record with site_id = 1.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Having Count Statement.  Something like that:

```
SELECT site_id
FROM site_merchant
HAVING (count(merchant_id) > 1)
GROUP BY site_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i found. I used @Gordons query to get started and what was missing was the site_id, and the group by was not needed:

```
SELECT 
    m.merchant_name,
    m.merchant_id,
    ut.realname,
    a.affiliate_name,
    (select (case when count(*)>0  then 'No' else 'Yes' end) as result
    from site_merchant sm
    WHERE sm.merchant_id = m.merchant_id
    AND site_id != 1) as isTjoos,
    (select (case when count(*)> 0 then 'No' else 'Yes' end) as result
    from site_merchant sm
    WHERE sm.merchant_id = m.merchant_id
    AND site_id != 2) as isUCOnly,
    (select (case when count(*)> 0 then 'No' else 'Yes' end) as result
    from site_merchant sm
    WHERE sm.merchant_id = m.merchant_id
    AND site_id != 3) as isDLKonly
FROM merchant m
LEFT JOIN merchant_editor_assignment mea ON mea.merchant_id = m.merchant_id
LEFT JOIN user_table ut ON ut.user_id = mea.user_id
LEFT JOIN affiliate a ON a.affiliate_id = m.affiliate_id_default
```

Thank you for the help.